# Softdeletes laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy implementando softdeletes con los clientes registrados en el sistema, estos clientes se relacionan con el modelo company al querer visualizar en mi datatables aquellos que han sido eliminados, solo puedo observar los datos de la tabla clients. Los datos de la tabla company no se pueden visualizar

> 0: {id: "6", name_client: "Elijah Schmitt", lastname: "Daugherty", address: "Suite 610",…}
>   id: "6"
>   name_client: "Elijah Schmitt"
>   lastname: "Daugherty"
>   address: "Suite 610"
>   city: "Lake Christa"
>   province: "Nebraska"
>   postal_code: "11730"
>   country: "Haiti"
>   phone_client: "+1872884775841"
>   email: "torp.axel@bogan.org"
>   deleted_at: "18-12-19"
>   created_at: "2002-07-07 00:00:00"
>   updated_at: "2019-12-18 10:36:06"
>   company: null

**la relacion con company es null**

controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DataTables;
use App\Client;
use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ClientRestoreController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.customers.restore');
    }



    public function dataTable()
    {

        $clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->with('company')      
        ->get();

        return dataTables::of($clientes)
                ->addColumn('id', function ($clientes){
                    return $clientes->id;
                })  

                ->addColumn('cliente', function ($clientes){
                    return 
                            '<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>'.' '.$clientes->company['name_company']."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$clientes->company['phone_company']."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i>'.' '.$clientes->company['web'];

                })

                ->addColumn('contacto', function ($clientes){
                    return
                            '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.' '.$clientes->name_client."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$clientes->phone_client."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>'.' '.$clientes->email;
                })
                ->addColumn('deleted_at', function ($clientes){
                    return $clientes->deleted_at->format('d-m-y');
                })                  


                ->addIndexColumn()   
                ->rawColumns(['cliente', 'contacto', 'deleted_at'])                
                ->make(true);          
    }
}
```

La relacion con company es null.
Porque esto no funciona:

```
 $clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->with('company')      
        ->get();
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

Modificando esto:

```
$clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->with('company')      
        ->get()
```

a esto:

```
$clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->get()->map(function ($client) {
            $client->deleted_client = $client->company()->withTrashed()->first();
            return $client;
        });
```

observo en la consola lo siguiente:

```
0: {id: "6", name_client: "Elijah Schmitt", lastname: "Daugherty", address: "Suite 610",…}
id: "6"
name_client: "Elijah Schmitt"
lastname: "Daugherty"
address: "Suite 610"
city: "Lake Christa"
province: "Nebraska"
postal_code: "11730"
country: "Haiti"
phone_client: "+1872884775841"
email: "torp.axel@bogan.org"
deleted_at: "18-12-19"
created_at: "2002-07-07 00:00:00"
updated_at: "2019-12-18 10:36:06"
deleted_client: {id: "6", client_id: "6", name_company: "acerind", cuit: "20-12345432-12", web: null,…}
id: "6"
client_id: "6"
name_company: "acerind"
cuit: "20-12345432-12"
web: null
phone_company: "03424562111"
deleted_at: "2019-12-18 10:36:06"
created_at: "2019-12-18 00:00:00"
updated_at: "2019-12-18 10:36:06"
cliente: "<i class="fa fa-industry"></i> <br><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <br><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> "
contacto: "<i class="fa fa-user"></i> Elijah Schmitt<br><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> +1872884775841<br><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> torp.axel@bogan.org"
DT_RowIndex: 1
input: {draw: "1", columns: [,…], order: [{column: "0", dir: "asc"}], start: "0", length: "10",…}
```

Con esto logro traer la compania asociada al cliente, pero ahora no puedo acceder a esos datos?.
Me refiero a esto:

```
->addColumn('cliente', function ($clientes){
                    return 
                            '<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>'.' '.$clientes->deleted_client->company['name_company']."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$clientes->deleted_client->company['phone_company']."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i>'.' '.$clientes->deleted_client->company['web'];

                })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes editar el modelo para incluir los eliminados pero eso afectaria a todas tus consultas. Te recomiendo hagas mutaciones a la relación de la siguiente forma.

```
$clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->get()->map(function ($client) {
    $client->deleted_client = $client->company()->withTrashed()->first();
    return $client;
});
```

De esta forma te refieres a cada uno de los clientes y obtienes su compañía aun cuando esta haya sido eliminada.

Para ver el registro obtenido debes apuntar al objeto directamente

```
//Sustituir 
$clientes->deleted_client->company['name_company']

//Por esto
$clientes->deleted_client->name_company
```

Comment: ese cambio lo realizo dentro de mi metodo datatables?  cambiar  esto:         ```$clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->with('company')      
        ->get();```  por esto ```$clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->get()->map(function ($client) {
    $client->deleted_client = $client->company()->withTrashed()->first();
    return $client;
});```

Comment: Si, debes sustituirlo ahí

Comment: asi es como estoy tratando de acceder, aun no logro mostrar el nombre de la compania que le pertenece al cliente. Actualice mi pregunta puedes mirarla?

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: Observa mi respuesta editada para resolver tu caso

Answer (score 0):

Con estos cambios puedo acceder al cliente eliminado por el metodo softdeletes, en este caso la compania que le pertenece a un cliente.

```
public function dataTable()
    {        

        $clientes = Client::onlyTrashed()->get()->map(function ($client) {
            $client->deleted_client = $client->company()->withTrashed()->first();
            return $client;
        });    


        return dataTables::of($clientes)
                ->addColumn('id', function ($clientes){
                    return $clientes->id;
                })  

                ->addColumn('cliente', function ($clientes){
                    return 
                            '<i class="fa fa-industry"></i>'.' '.$clientes->deleted_client['name_company']."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$clientes->deleted_client['phone_company']."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-globe"></i>'.' '.$clientes->deleted_client['web'];

                })

                ->addColumn('contacto', function ($clientes){
                    return
                            '<i class="fa fa-user"></i>'.' '.$clientes->name_client."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>'.' '.$clientes->phone_client."<br>".
                            '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>'.' '.$clientes->email;
                })
                ->addColumn('deleted_at', function ($clientes){
                    return $clientes->deleted_at->format('d-m-y');
                })                  


                ->addIndexColumn()   
                ->rawColumns(['cliente', 'contacto', 'deleted_at'])                
                ->make(true);          
    }
```